# how can access to key withouth know the name of the key

Tags: javascript

I want to access the property `nombreprofesional`, noting that I do not know what the property is called. I want to avoid doing `myVar.errors["nombreprofesional"]`. How would he do it?

```
var myVar={
  "errors": {
   "nombreprofesional": [
   "El contenido ingresado en nombreprofesional es inválido."
   ]
  }
}
```

Comment: @benvc `Object.prototype.keys` is not a thing. You probably mean `Object.keys(myVar)`.

Comment: Thanks @deceze for correcting my initial erroneous syntax (deleted comment so as not to confuse future readers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
var key=Object.keys(myVar.errors)[0];
myVar.errors[key];
```

If you know that there is only ever one key in the error object. Otherwise you could loop through all the keys

```
for (var k in myVar.errors){
    if (!myVar.errors.hasWonProperty(k)){continue;}
    myVar.errors[k];
}
```